# Multiple if & then clause for two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with this if and then clause, there are multiples and I am confused on how I can achieve this. This column should have just either primary or secondary date based on the below clauses.

- PRIMARY   date: `i_sched_dt`
- SECONDARY date: `h_sched_dt`

Conditions:

- if h_sched_dt is not null and i_sched_dt is null
  then = SECONDARY date
- if only h_sched_dt date exists = SECONDARY date
- if only i_sched_dt date exists = PRIMARY date
- if both dates exist then if today is before SECONDARY date then PRIMARY  else SECONDARY date

Comment: I'm sure as you typed this question multiple suggestions would have come up. What you need to look into is the case.. when statement.

Comment: what is the formal date another column? please provide a [mre] and read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nbk - no it's the secondary date...it was a typo

Comment: The first two cases... are the same one. Aren't they? Can't spot any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cascade `CASE WHEN` as much as you like

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN h_sched_dt IS NOT NULL AND i_sched_dt  IS NULL THEN h_sched_dt 
     WHEN h_sched_dt IS NULL AND i_sched_dt  IS NOT NULL THEN i_sched_dt  
     WHEN h_sched_dt IS NOT NULL AND i_sched_dt  IS NOT NULL 
         THEN CASE WHEN cast(h_sched_dt  as date) < cast(GETDATE() as date) 
             THEN h_sched_dt   ELSE i_sched_dt  END
     ELSE NULL
END mydate
FROM mytable
```

Comment: I am getting the "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" so I updated the as date to datetime2 still I am getting the same error for this line.

Comment: to debug your problem i need a https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV- where you add your create table and data, at least the part that is needed

Comment: That worked, I had to fix the 'h_sched_dt' with AS varchar(20).  Thanks for your help!